# Semantic ui React css file not compiling/working with webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, semantic-ui

I am making a basic CRA app and wanted to use semantic-ui i followed the steps to the same but as soon as I import the CSS file in the index.js the app starts compiling and finishes it with two errors i dont know what I am doing wrong.

Here are the errors being shown

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
during rendering of asset asset/inline|data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqyU.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1z0.png

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to take on the burden of installing a "patch package" as described on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4287), you could alternatively run the same hacky code locally as a custom webpack loader:

**src/css-preloader.js**

```
module.exports = function(source) {
  return source.replace(/;;/g, ';');
}
```

then update your **webpack.config.js** as follows:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader', 
        path.resolve('src/css-preloader.js')
    ],
}
```

Comment: I actually like this solution, not much of a fan of installing a package that changes the source code inside another package.

Answer (score 0):

The main [reason](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/issues/75) for this is an extra ";" at line 19990 of semantic.css
If removed, everything goes fine. In the 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css' remove the extra ';'.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Step';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;;base64,AAEAAAAOAIAAAw...
}
```

Comment: Theres a patch for this here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4287#issuecomment-1016579332 from the Semantic UI React team that should help, but its definitely a hack. Came here searching for a better solution

Comment: But I did just test it out, and it seems to work pretty well...

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/7073#issuecomment-1001074430

The error is likely to caused by double semicolons in `semantic.min.css`

Temporary (but not quite good) solution: add `sed -i 's/;;/;/g' node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css &&` in front of your start/build script in `package.json`